# How to retrieve a number of visible divs on a page and displaying a count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have approximately 1000 divs called "itemcontainer" on the page. 
I also have a number of checkboxes which allow me to filter these items.

I would like to display "# of returned results" at the top of the page. The "#" being the actual number of divs returned.

Currently I have:

```
var divCount = $('.item-container:visible').length;
            $('.header').append(contactCount);
```

When clicking a filter, it displays the visible results. However, if I uncheck a filter, or check another, it shows the visible item account in additional to the previous result.

For example. There's 1000 items. I click a checkbox. It displays 604 at the top of the page. I uncheck the checkbox and it'll display 6041000.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: a class selector with a pseudo selector on 1000 elements might yield low performances. consider using a class for visible items and prepend the html element `$('div.item-container.visible')`

Comment: performance comparison http://jsperf.com/david-1000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.header').text(contactCount);
```

Should do the trick. See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for more details.

Comment: The previous response of .html worked brilliantly! Thanks Xan!

Comment: @Mattius Either should work fine for what you want, but `.html()` is intended for passing a string containing `html` snippets (ie including markup), whereas `.text()` is intended for just setting the text / contents of the selected element(s).

Comment: ah! I see. Thanks for pointing that out. Is there anyway to display the item count on page load before filtering?

Comment: You could run your existing piece of javascript when the DOM is first loaded to show the inital number. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for details.

Alternatively, if your page is being generated by a server side process (PHP / ASP.Net / MVC.Net etc. etc.) you may know how many itemou have to begin with and could pre-fill the content of the "#number of items" box.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you use the append function. It does append what you give to it to the DOM. I recommend specifying a span and than use the html function to set the content of that span.

```
var divCount = $('.item-container:visible').length;
$('#counter').html(divCount);
```

Comment: I think you can just call that code on document.ready and it should work fine.

Comment: I gave that a go - It returns zero. Appreciate the help from you both so far. Thank you

Comment: are the divs already there or are created by javascript later?

Comment: Sorry David, I completely missed your original post. Thank you for the feedback. All items (divs) are available on page load.

Comment: seems strange, are you sure you are executing it inside the *ready* method? are you sure they are `:visible`?

Comment: Yeah - On load it reads as zero. Open the console and check the the length and it displays as 1000. Once you start filtering and removing filtering it'll show the correct amount. I agree. Very unusual.